# Linq - Query tables without FK

Tags: linq

I have the following tables.

```
 Persons       Animals        Logs
---------     ----------     --------
Id               Id             Id
Name             Spicie         Type
                                EntityId
                                Log
```

Logs table stores logs that could come from Persons or Animals tables, so the field EntityId could be an Id from Persons or Animals. This means that EntityId is not a FK to Persons or Animals Id field.

Now I want to make some Persons logs searchs using Linq.

I'm using the following query:

```
var personsQuery = Uow.Set<Persons>();

var logsQuery = Uow.Set<Logs>().Where(entity =>
                            entity.Type == "EntityAdded");

personsQuery = personsQuery.Join(logsQuery,
                    person => person.Id,
                    log => log.EntityId,
                    (person, log) => person);
```

The query works fine, but I don't know if it's the best approach to do that. I cannot use includes because the fields Id from Persons and EntityId from Logs are not related by a foreign key.

Is there a better way to do that query?

Thanks

Comment: If it's correct, no. But is it correct? How do you know that `EntityId` points to `Persons` and not `Animals`? They may have same Id values.

Comment: Sorry because I forget to comment that Persons and Animals couldn't have the same ids.